# How can I check how does a MatLab function work? I want to check the algorithm for dspdata.psd

Tags: matlab

I am trying to make Power Spectral Density function in Mathematica and seems like MatLab [dpsdata.psd](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/signal/ref/dspdata.psd.html) works quite well. Now, I want to implement this to Mathematica but I need how it works and its algorithm. How can I check this?

Comment: Is this not what you want? http://reference.wolfram.com/applications/timeseries/UsersGuideToTimeSeries/SpectralAnalysis/1.8.1.html

Comment: In the Matlab command window, you can type `edit dpsdata`. This opens the function/method/class in the editor. However, some Matlab code is proprietary. In that case, you'll only see the help content but no actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Type `edit dspdata.psd` in the Matlab shell. You'll see the code, mostly comments, and then a call to `initialize`.  Click on that word and hit <kbd>F4</kbd>. You'll then see the code you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `open dspdata.psd` or `edit dspdata.psd` in the MATLAB Command Window to view the source code. You can also call `open initialize`, which will bring up the key function in dspdata.psd.

It may help to review MathWorks's reference pages for this function, available here http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/dspdata.html and here http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/dspdata.psd.html.